# What is the grammatical function of "As soon as I know"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

***"If, at the end of a conversation somebody says to me, “As soon as I know, I’ll ring you up”, he is taking too much for granted."***

Is "As soon as I know" is an object clause? I kown an object clause is an independent sentence that serves as the object of another sentence, in this case does "ring you up"an object clause? The purpose of this object clause is to explain the condition of "ring you up"?

Comment: "As soon as" is a prepositional idiom functioning as an adjunct of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - *As soon as I know* can't be an [object clause](https://icaltefl.com/object-clauses%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E-in-english-grammar/#:%7E:text=Examples%20of%20Object%20Clauses&text=I%20know%20he%20is%20lying,tax%20authorities%20with%20false%20information.), because it's not a potential "sentence" in its own right - it's just a noun phrase used as an "adverb of time".

Compare *I'll go **on Tuesday**, I'll call **tomorrow**, I'll tell you **as soon as I know***.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

> *If, at the end of a conversation somebody says to me, “As soon as I*
> *know, I’ll ring you up”, he is taking too much for granted.*

"As soon as" is a prepositional idiom with the declarative content clause "I know" as its complement.

The direct speech clause "As soon as I know, I’ll ring you up" is functioning as complement of "say", where the preposition phrase "as soon as I know" is an adjunct of time in clause structure.

Comment: Thank you for your response!